# Как прятать пароль под звездочками?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как при вводе пароля отображать звездочки `****` вместо вводимых символов?

Желательно, чтобы звездочки были с таким же размером как и шрифт.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/2555984/1548895

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У `textBox` есть свойство `UseSystemPasswordChar`, сделайте `true` или если Вы хотите произвольный символ, воспользуйтесь свойством `PasswordChar`. Из программного кода:

```
textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
```

или

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Comment: Спасибо! и за способ с произвольным символом.